# Is there a character limit for posting answers?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Someone told me that there is a character limit while posting answers, is there really a limit or is it a bug? if there is a limit than what is it?

Comment: I retagged this as [tag:support] since it is about a site feature not a bug.

Comment: What gave you the impression that character-limit is a bug?

Comment: well if there was never a character limit for answers than it must be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think there character limit is a really good **feature**. Often answers are ignored because they're way too long, so no one would read the whole document posted as answer. Since we're here to help people and ourselves to understand the religion better, I think **going directly to the main point** and keeping the answer at a reasonable length would encourage people to read it.

[Reading this might help.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers)